# Getting "use of moved value" compile error from calling .count() on a char array

Tags: rust

I am trying to understand why I am getting compile error "use of moved value: `chars`" from the sample code below.

The `chars.count()` is returning a number value and should not be referring to the `chars` var itself.

```
pub fn iter_num(num: i32) -> bool {

    let num_str = num.to_string();
    let chars = num_str.chars(); // <-- move occurs because `chars` has type `Chars<'_>`, which does not implement the `Copy` trait
    let len = chars.count();     // <-- `chars` moved due to this method call

    println!("Len = {:?}", len);

    for c in chars {             // <-- ❌ "value used here after move": chars
        println!(">>> {:?}", c);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Comment: Counting values will consume the iterator. https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/str/struct.Chars.html#method.count "Consumes the iterator, counting the number of iterations and returning it"

Comment: `let len = chars.clone().count();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the other answers say, chars is an iterator, so `chars.count()` will literally iterate over all the characters and return the count, thereby consuming the iterator so you can't use it again.

Here are some options to rewrite it:

1. Collect (copy) all the chars into a vector of char (uses a lot of memory though):

```rust
pub fn iter_num(num: i32) -> bool {

    let num_str = num.to_string();
    let chars: Vec<char> = num_str.chars().collect();
    let len = chars.len();

    println!("Len = {:?}", len);

    for c in chars {
        println!(">>> {:?}", c);
    }

    return true;
}
```

2. Do the count as you iterate (probably the most efficient)

```rust
pub fn iter_num(num: i32) -> bool {

    let num_str = num.to_string();

    let mut count = 0;

    for c in num_str.chars() {
        println!(">>> {:?}", c);
        count += 1;
    }

    println!("Len = {:?}", count);

    return true;
}
```

3. Same as above, but written more functional programming style (my favorite)

```rust
pub fn iter_num(num: i32) -> bool {

    let num_str = num.to_string();

    let len = num_str.chars()
         .inspect(|c| println!(">>> {:?}", c))
         .count();

    println!("Len = {:?}", len);

    return true;
}
```

4. Because the source is a number, you can assume that all characters are from 0..9 ASCII, and therefore use one byte of UTF-8, so just use the string length rather than counting UTF-8 chars.

```rust
pub fn iter_num(num: i32) -> bool {

    let num_str = num.to_string();

    println!("Len = {:?}", num_str.len());

    num_str.chars().for_each(|c| println!(">>> {:?}", c));

    return true;
}
```

5. Just go through the list of chars twice; once to count them, and a second time to print them:

```rust
pub fn iter_num(num: i32) -> bool {

    let num_str = num.to_string();

    println!("Len = {:?}", num_str.chars().count());

    for c in num_str.chars() {
        println!(">>> {:?}", c);
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your code snippet, the `num_str` is of type String.

Then the `chars()` method returns a value of type [Chars<'_>](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html) which is an iterator over the characters in the string.

If you look at [the documentation for the count method](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.Chars.html#method.count):

> pub fn count(self) -> usize
> Consumes the iterator, counting the number of iterations and returning it

This means that the `chars` variable cannot be reused after this call. It has indeed been moved into the function, and dropped within.

In your specific case, since you are converting an integer into a string using the default settings, it means that you will obtain a string only containing decimal digits, and optionally a leading minus sign.

What does this mean? Basically that you can interpret your string as a slice of u8 where each byte corresponds to a digit, and you can directly obtain its length without the need to iterate:

```
let num_str = num.to_string();
let len = num_str.len();
```

Comment: `num_str.len()` will return the size in bytes, not the size in characters (not to say that the size in characters is very useful but…)

Comment: @Masklinn Please make sure to read my answer. In this **specific** case, the string is guaranteed to contain characters which are decimal numbers, ie only one byte-wide in UTF-8. I insist on **specific** as this indeed does not apply if the string contains arbitrary characters.

Comment: yes but it's useless to say that, also, I'm sure I could think some funny unicode digit

Answer (score 2):

> The `chars.count()` is returning a number value and should not be referring to the chars var itself.

The error says *moved*, not referred. That's because [`count()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.count) is a method which comes from `Iterator`, and that means the *way* it works is to go through the entire iterator and count the number of elements as it discards them. Since it consumes the entire iterator, it might as well, well, consume the iterator object itself. Which is what it does.

Now you could simply have called [`by_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.by_ref)`.count()`, but since the iterator is entirely traversed anyway you'd have had a count of, say, 5… and then nothing would have printed because Rust iterators are not "repeatable", which turns out not to be very helpful.

The solution is to just call `chars()` twice or clone the iterator, once to count the number of characters and once to iterate the characters. [`chars()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.chars) actually comes from `&str` so it doesn't consume anything, it just borrows the string.